# XAMPP Apache not running, path issue

Tags: php, xampp

I'm having a problem with my XAMPP Control Panel. The Apache won't run, I tried reinstalling it and allowed the Apache and its http.exe in my firewall. And I also tired editing the port Listen and its server localhost name in the Apache(httpd.conf) like what the other sites were suggesting. ( i don't have a Skype too) help.

[image]

Comment: Do you have skype or IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Click on `httpd.conf`

[image]

and change `Listen 80` to `Listen 8181`, now you can access it as `http://localhost:8181`  and here as well `ServerName localhost:8181`

**OR**

close your skpype and start it and then start using skype.
PS: You can use `80` from skype settings as well if you want to use `80` part with `apache`

Comment: does it include changing the server locahostname to 8181? or im just gonna leave it as 80?

Comment: @Jushiro kindly mark it as answered if that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

skype might be the issue. Tools ->connection option-> uncheck "use port 80 ...." -> save and restart Skype and try

Comment: skype is not installed in my computer

Answer (score 0):

Ahh you have installed xamppp to C:\Program Files (x86), right? Have you reinstalled xampp to C:\xampp and tried?